# The value of x satisfying $\int^{2[x+14]}_0\{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =\int^{\{x\}}_0[x+14]dx $ where [.] .....

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Problem :

The value of x satisfying $\int^{2[x+14]}_0\{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =\int^{\{x\}}_0[x+14]dx $ where [.] denotes the greatest integer function and $\{.\}$ denotes the fractional part function.

Solution : $\int^{2[x+14]}_0\{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =\int^{\{x\}}_0[x+14]dx $

$\Rightarrow \int^{2[x]+ 28}_0\{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =\int^{\{x\}}_0[x]+14dx $

$\Rightarrow \int^{28}_0 \{\frac{x}{2}\}dx +\int^{28+2[x]}_{28} \{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =(14+[x])\{x\} $

[ Using $\int^{nT}_0f(x)dx =n \int^T_0 f(x) dx $ and $\int^{a+nT}_a f(x)dx =\int^{nT}_0f(x)dx ;$ where T is period of f(x) ]

$\Rightarrow 14 + \int^{28+2[x]}_{28} \{\frac{x}{2}\}dx =(14+[x])\{x\}dx$

I don't have any idea how to solve $\int^{28+2[x]}_{28} \{\frac{x}{2}\}dx $ this part. Please suggest thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that:
$$\{x\}=x - \lfloor x \rfloor = x + \lceil -x \rceil$$
Where $\lfloor x \rfloor, \lceil x \rceil$ are the floor and ceiling functions respectively.

This turns your "fractional part" problem into a "greatest integer" problem, which you have already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this problem recently. I am posting my solution to it,
Hope it helps.

PAGE 1
[image]

PAGE 2
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures